# module.js:549 throw err;

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
> module.js:549
>     throw err;
>     ^
> 
> Error: Cannot find module '..models/category'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mridul/shafee-it/routes/admin.js:2:18)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mridul/shafee-it/server.js:74:21)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:565:32) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is my ..models/category(category schema)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true, uppercase: true}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

add-category Route in admin.js file

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Category = require('..models/category');

// add-category route
router.get('/add-category', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('admin/add-category', { message: req.flash('success') });
});


router.post('/add-category', function(req, res, next) {
    var category = new Category();
    category.name = req.body.name;

    category.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        req.flash('success', 'Successfully added a category');
        return res.redirect('/add-category');
    });
});
```

Here also server.js file to include the category

```
const Category = require('./models/category');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    Category.find({}, function(err, categories) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.locals.categories = categories;
        next();
    });
});

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');

app.use(adminRoutes);
```

- when i run my server or route the add-category url then show module.js:549 throw err; this problem.
  Here is my problem details and i check my code different times.
  Then how can i solve this problem.

Comment: This might just be a typo. Should the path in `const Category = require('..models/category');` be `'./models/category'`?

Comment: I can try this but it's throw also this error module.js:549 throw err;

Comment: If it's within the same directory then `./models/category`. If it's a directory up, then it's `../models/category`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you forgot a `/`:

> `require('..models/category');`
>
> `require('../models/category');`

This is why `..models/category` throws an error. From a general point of view, when `require` can't find a local module, don't "check the code", just check where the file is, and what path you wrote, it's always one or the other. ;)